# SQL Server - Inserting new data worsens query performance

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012, left-join, batch-processing

We have a 4-5TB SQL Server database. The largest table is around 800 GB big containing 100 million rows. 4-5 other comparable tables are 1/3-2/3 of this size. We went through a process to create new indexes to optimize performance. While the performance certainly improved we saw that the newly inserted data was slowest to query.

It's a financial reporting application with a BI tool working on top of the database. The data is loaded overnight continuing in the late morning, though the majority of the data is loaded by 7am. Users start to query data around 8am through the BI tool and are most concerned with the latest (daily) data.

I wanted to know if newly inserted data causes indexes to go out of order. Is there anything we can do so that we get better performance on the newly inserted data than the old data. I hope I have explained the issue well here. Let me know in case of any missing information. Thanks

**Edit 1**

Let me describe the architecture a bit. 
I have a base table (let’s call it Base) with Date,id as clustered index. 
It has around 50 columns
Then we have 5 derived tables (Derived1, Derived2,...) , according to different metric types, which also have Date,Id as clustered index and foreign key constraint on the Base table.

Tables Derived1 and Derived2 have 350+ columns. Derived3,4,5 have around 100-200 columns. There is one large view created to join all the data tables due limitations of the BI tool. The date,ID are the joining columns for all the tables joining to form the view (Hence I created clustered index on those columns). The main concern is with regard to BI tool performance. The BI tool always uses the view and generally sends similar queries to the server.

There are other indexes as well on other filtering columns. 
The main question remains - how to prevent performance from deteriorating. 
In addition I would like to know

1. If NCI on Date,ID on all tables would be better bet in addition to the clustered index on date,ID.
2. Does it make sense to have 150 columns as included in NCI for the derived tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have about a 100 million rows, increasing every day with new portions and those new portions are usually selected. I should use partitioned indexes with those numbers and not regular indexes.
Your solution within sql server would be partitioning. Take a look at sql partitioning and see if you can adopt it. Partitioning is a form of clustering where groups of data share a physical block. If you use year and month for example, all 2018-09 records will share the same physical space and easy to be found. So if you select records with those filters (and plus more) it is like the table has the size of 2018-09 records. That is not exactly accurate but its is quite like it. Be careful with data values for partitioning - opposite to standard PK clusters where each value is unique, partitioning column(s) should result a nice set of different unique combinations thus partitions.

If you cannot use partitions you have to create 'partitions' yourself using regular indexes. This will require some experiments. The basic idea is data (a number?) indicating e.g. a wave or set of waves of imported data. Like data imported today and the next e.g. 10 days will be wave '1'. Next 10 days will be '2' and so on. Filtering on the latest e.g. 10 waves, you work on the latest 100 days import effectively skip out all the rest data. Roughly, if you divided your existing 100 million rows to 100 waves and start on at wave 101 and search for waves 90 or greater then you have 10 million rows to search if SQL is put correctly to use the new index first (will do eventually)

Comment: I implemented partitioning, compression on tables and indexes. I see that the results are good with update statistics, FULLSCAN. However, this requires to be done everyday. Question to you and @dfundako - how often should one be doing update Stats and how long should it take.   Does long running update stats suggest issue with design?

Comment: Usually after lots of data modification. There are several indicators that can help to automatically decide if you do or not. Practically, you can also increase to every two days, then every three days and so on to see how actually performance decreases. Long time to update stats has more to do with data and statements executed against than schema design. A 'bad' schema will affect indirectly as stats credibility will be decreased for the optimizer to take decisions as many statements will delay nevertheless regardless different execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question especially without knowing your system. But one thing that I would try is manually update your stats on the indexes/table once you are done loading data. With tables that big, it is unlikely that you will manipulate enough rows to trigger an auto-update. Without clean stats, SQL Server won't have an accurate histogram of your data.

Next, dive into your execution plans and see what operators are the most expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try to schedule update stats after loading data and see how it works.